# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, remote-access

I am using jdbc to connect to a mysql database throw java. It works just fine when I am connecting to my localhost database. I want this database to be accessed from a remote pc, I singed up at freesqldatabase.com to get a database with remote access enabled. I got my username, password, sql server. I logged in using mysql workbench successfully. When I use the same exact info inside my java code replacing my localhost info I got this error !

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access
>   denied for user 'remoteserveruser'@'%' to database 'dbname'

I dunno what am I doing wrong. Is remote connection requires something to be changed inside the java code than it is in the local host or what?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you login to that remote  mysql server using workbench from your computer

Comment: This has nothing to do with code. Your database is telling you that user does have permission to access that db

Comment: Yes I can login to that remote mysql server using workbench from my pc.
If nothing wrong with the code and this remote server can be accessed from workbench, so where is the error?

Comment: MySQL sometimes gets fussy about the host name so make sure you have grant rights in the table for host name % and localhost and ip of the host machine. It's a MySQL thing.

Comment: I do can login with the same info from mysql workbench from the same pc.. does connecting using jdbc require granting some more rights?
If so what I am suppose to do exactly?